# Display table and position absolute conflicts

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

I have a strange behavior when I'm using a CSS table and a black layer that is with position absolute on top of the table in HTML.

When the layer is enabled, (`display: block`), then it's destroying the layout. But when I disable is (`display: none`), everything is fine.

Here is a small example (you have to change the css through the developer tools). Is there something that I forgot to set, etc?

It's not possible to use flexbox instead of the table!

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#menu {
  display: none;
  background: #28292D;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#blackLayer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 1265px;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 223px;
  background: #3d464d none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="blackLayer"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A table is a display value, if you change to block you break the table.

Comment: That's not what I wrote. I don't change the table to block. I change layer to block/none and the layer has position absolute.

Comment: The layer is inside a display table element, your body. At least is not a good practice and the table layout is broken because this, if you change all your markup you'll achieve the right behavior without weird coding

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

I think your markup is wrong. Wrap the `#sidebar` and `#content` in another `#container` and give it a `display:flex;` and `position:absolute;` and a `min-height:100%;`. Flex's `align-items:stretch;` will make your sidebar and content stretch their height to the parent height.

Try like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: row; /* children will fall side by side like columns */
  align-items: stretch; /* children will stretch to my height */
}
#menu {
  display: none;
  background: #28292D;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#blackLayer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 223px;
  background: #3d464d none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
#content {
  flex: 1 0; /* Now I will take remaining space left by my sister Ms. #sidebar */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="blackLayer"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not the same result. The sidebar is now invisible and has not the full height of the page. Also I don't see the point that `table-cell` has an effect on an div that has `position: absolute`.

Comment: Well keeping `table-cell` elements and any other type in the same container is not a good idea. Just like you will not put a `<div>` and a `<td>` together. Anyway I put a height for the `#container` and it made the sidebar and content visible.

Comment: I have that markup because I want always the full hight in the sidebar. That means that I want 100% height of the window if the content of the page is not filling 100%. And I want 100% height of the content if it's bigger than the height of the window. Now that's not working without javascript.

Comment: That's a flexbox solution. That's not working for me, because I'm working with a dynamic scrolling table and that's not working if I'm using flexbox before.